# Unable to Edit Main Navigation Drupal 8

Tags: theming, blocks, navigation

I installed a custom theme called [StartupGrowth](http://demo.morethanthemes.com/startupgrowth/default/). At the moment, I am trying to edit the main navigation. When I go to Structure->Menus->Main Navigation and disable the unneeded entries, they do not disappear from the navigation. However, if I add a new entry to the menu, it does appear. What's more, when I attempt to delete the entry added by me, it persists in the navigation just like the other ones.

What am I missing? Is there another place for editing this menu? Or does this sound like a bug in the theme itself?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to test for the ones not having this theme.

Looking at the demo for the theme I can see it is using Superfish module to display this menu.

So, after removing the menu element try to flush the cache (from /admin/config/development/performance). If still doesn't work, go check on Structure->Blocks and see the superfish block... click on configure and be sure it is using the same menu. You have more settings in there, and you can look into the module (Superfish) settings, too.

Comment: It turned out that the theme has some kind of a bug. Namely, the top level entries are not removable. A way to by-pass it is to make them sub-entries and then disable. It is a weird fix, but works for now :-) Thanks!

Comment: From what I have read and remember, I actually think it was a bug with Superfish ...